# Formatting a date for XML to include a UTC offset

Tags: java, groovy, datetime-format, utc, java-time

I'm generating an XML which contains a date in a valid `XML` format, and I need it to include a `UTC` offset as well.

I'm ussing `groovy` but I'll show the `Java` code I'm using instead (an answer in either language is good):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
long timeZoneOffset = c.timeZone.getOffset(c.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60*60);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
formatter.format(c.getTime()) + "+0" + timeZoneOffset + ":00";
```

The above code give4s me `2011-06-12T07:23:25.000+03:00`, but this code has two problems:

1. It is ugly, and probably not the best way to do this
2. It won't work for timezones like India (***GMT +5:30***), Nepal (***GMT +5:45***)

I tried using `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z")` for the timezone, but it gave me `2011-06-12T07:23:25.000+0300` which is not a correct format (`+0300` instead of `+03:00`).

Any other way to format the date the way I need it? (preferably without 3rd parties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other alternative - also buried inside jaxb api - (not needing Jodatime):

```
    Calendar c = ...
    String printDate = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks - this is the simplest solution which is available everywhere JRE6 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most elegant way is to use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library. You need ISO 8601 (Section 5.4) format (as represented by `xs:dateTime` XSD type):

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
 System.out.println(fmt.print(dt));
```

Result:

> 2011-06-12T07:36:32.294+02:00

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html)?  For example:

```
Calendar c = ...
DataTypeFactory f = DataTypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar xc = f.newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
String str = xc.toXMLFormat();
```

If the calendar is a date-time with a timezone offset, then the timezone offset should be included in the result String formatted as per the XML Datatypes specification.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDataFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
supports a format specifier letter of X which includes the colon ":" in the time zone. Its worth reading the sectiona about time zones and in particular the part about "ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone"

Using the format string "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.sssXXX" gave me 2015.05.07 15:06:58.058+10:00

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> not only makes it easy to do but the solution also looks lucid and natural.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtNepal = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kathmandu"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
        System.out.println(zdtIndia);
        System.out.println(zdtNepal);

        // If you do not need to display the time zone name, convert it into
        // OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odtNewYork = zdtNewYork.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odtNewYork);

        // Using DateTimeFormatter, you can display it in different formats
        String odtFormat = zdtNewYork.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
        String dayMonFullNameFormat = zdtNewYork.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d MMMM uuuu HH:mm:ssXXX"));
        System.out.println(odtFormat);
        System.out.println(dayMonFullNameFormat);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-09T16:41:23.683709-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-05-10T02:11:23.685131+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2021-05-10T02:26:23.685187+05:45[Asia/Kathmandu]
2021-05-09T16:41:23.683709-04:00
2021-05-09T16:41:23.683709-04:00
Sunday 9 May 2021 16:41:23-04:00
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>